# Why I'm not editing posts?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I know that I don't have 2k of reputation but since a long time ago (I don't remember when) I was able to suggest edition for the questions, just using the *edit* link below it. After this, a message saying that my suggestion would be reviewed appears. OK.

But today I'm not able to edit any question anymore.

The *edit* link is off and a label saying that my user profile has not privileges to edit posts appears.

Why?

**edit:** here is a screenshot showing the off link and the label.

[image]

Comment: Is this the case for all of your SE accounts, or just some?

Comment: @robjohn, just this one.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4672/856) happened: "If a user (anonymous or registered) submits many rejected edits they will be automatically banned from suggesting edits for 7 days." *Edit:* Although it doesn't look like a lot of [your recent suggested edits](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/31682/sigur?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) were rejected, so that may not be the reason.

Comment: The [suggested edit queue](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) is usually empty, so that is probably not the explanation, either.

Comment: Looking into the specifics of [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78192), here is [the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92337) that Shog9 showed to me. Since you do not have have 16 rejections in the last 7 days, this is not the reason.

Comment: @robjohn It is `(rejects - (approvals / 3)) > 5` according to the comment given there. So in the worst case scenario, 6 rejects would suffice.

Comment: I've checked the last 10 of [Sigur's suggested edits](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/31682/sigur?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).
I only see 4 of them rejected:
[44255](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/44255),
[43835](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/43835),
[43778](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/43778),
[43578](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/43578).
(Although I am not sure what does it mean, when an edit is rejected by the Community user.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Ah! Correct you are. I misplaced the parentheses when I read it.

Comment: In the last $7$ days, however, I count $5$ rejections and $6$ acceptances. $5-(6/3)=3\le5$. That doesn't look as if it qualifies.

Comment: @robjohn And I surely hope that SE software does not count rejections by Community, which merely mean that there was a  collision of edits and another user's edit was kept.

Comment: @5PM, I have been noticed many times this kind of problem. I type a lot of corrections and when I submit it I got a message that other user did it first. So I lost my edits.

Comment: Another possibility: the OP might be at some meta site.

Comment: @Sigur: just to be sure, is this on main that you cannot make suggested edits?

Comment: @Novice: yes, I just found out that suggested edits are disabled on meta.

Comment: Screenshot, please

Comment: @Shog9, I edited the post.

Comment: Turns out that answer was *slightly* incorrect, @rob. I've fixed it.

Comment: So, the problem is related to the fact that my suggested edits was overwritten by other users edits, that is it? They were not rejected?

Answer (score 3):

6 out of the 11 suggested edits you made last week were rejected. [Per this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days/92337#92337) (which I've now corrected to reflect what the code was actually doing), you'll be able to edit again sometime next Wednesday.

5PM points out that most of these rejections were due to edit conflicts - unfortunately, [there's currently no exception for these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137611/suggested-edit-rejections-for-concurrent-edits-should-not-count-for-the-suggeste).

Comment: Does it matter that 4 of 6 rejections were by `Community`, which are likely to be edit conflicts rather than unhelpful edits?

Comment: No, that makes no difference. It probably should: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137611/suggested-edit-rejections-for-concurrent-edits-should-not-count-for-the-suggeste

Comment: @Shog9: I count 5 rejections and 6 approvals in 7 days for Sigur:
$(5-(6/3))=3<5$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @robjohn Maybe the one that ended up being "Improved" counts as a rejection?

Comment: Turns out it was [this rejection](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/43777) on a now-deleted question that was missing from the activity feed.

Comment: @5PM: It turns out that I didn't see one of the rejections since the post had been deleted and I counted one too many approvals (off by ~20 hours).

Comment: Aha, so it was actually 5 Community pseudo-rejections out of 6 total. Enough to make me visit Meta.SO and upvote the aforementioned [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137611/206169)